# Mark exception as 'handled' so IExceptionLogger does not log it

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I'm using Web API 2 w/ ExceptionFilterAttributes registered in my HttpConfig.Fitlers collection so they execute on all actions.  For some handlers, I want to swallow the exception and return a valid response.  I set the `actionFilterContext.Response` property, but I see the `IExceptionLogger` is still being called and I get a log of the exception!

Is there a way to mark the exception as handled so it doesn't end up in my logs?

(NOTE: I tried switching to use an IExceptionHandler and saw the same problem).